# How to simply disable client side validation in Tapestry 5 for 1 page

Tags: jquery, tapestry, currency-formatting

I have one page that requires simple validation of a text field bound to a double variable in my page class. This is accomplished by [jquery-formatcurrency](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-formatcurrency/) which also styles values( "0.0" to "$0.00").

```
<t:textfield t:id="bills" value="projection.current"/>
```

However now when the field fires the blur event or the page is submitted tapestry says:

```
You must provide a numeric value for bills
```

(obviously due to the "$")

So my thinking is to disable validation for just this one page because jquery-formatcurrency can more than handle the validation. Then I can just override the translator as it states in the tapestry docs for [Overriding the Translator with Events](http://tapestry.apache.org/forms-and-validation.html#FormsandValidation-OverridingtheTranslatorwithEvents) to process the form field.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<t:form t:clientValidation="none">
```

...will disable client validation on your form.

You can also do clientValidation="submit" which validates on submit rather than onBlur, you might try that?

More info:

http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/Form.html
http://tapestry.apache.org/5.3.7/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/ClientValidation.html